# Python: how to delete object from class?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm new to python and having a little trouble with object classes. I have created code were ball objects bounce off the side of the wall. I would like to delete a ball after it has been clicked on. I have tried several different methods of doing this but they have all resulted in errors. Below is my code for the balls bouncing off the walls. How can I edit this code to have the balls deleted once they are clicked? Thanks!

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
import time

canvasWidth=480
canvasHeight=320


root= Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root,width=canvasWidth,height=canvasHeight, bg='white')
root.title('RaspPi')
canvas.pack()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
            self.ballSize = 30
            self.xposition = random.randint(0 + self.ballSize, canvasWidth - self.ballSize)
            self.yposition = random.randint(0 + self.ballSize, canvasHeight - self.ballSize)
            self.shape=canvas.create_oval(self.xposition,self.yposition,self.xposition+self.ballSize,self.yposition+self.ballSize, fill='black',activefill="grey",width=0)
            self.xspeed = random.randrange(-3,3)
            self.yspeed = random.randrange(-3,3)



    def move(self):
        canvas.move(self.shape, self.xspeed, self.yspeed)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        if pos[2] >= canvasWidth or pos[0] <= 0:
            self.xspeed = -self.xspeed
        if pos[3] >= canvasHeight or pos[1] <= 0:
            self.yspeed = -self.yspeed


balls=[]
for i in range(20):
    balls.append(Ball())

while True:
    for ball in balls:
        ball.move()

    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This seems more of a problem on the tkinter side then the Python side.

Comment: errr, just remove the corresponding instance from the `balls` list, the deleted object won't be iterated upon.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with "delet[ing] object[s] from [a] class". You need to read the Tkinter API to learn how to remove an object from the game.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre They will still be showed in the Tkinter window. They also need to be deleted from the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bind-method of the class canvas and delete the clicked oval. Your for loop should have an exception handling because a deleted object can't have coordiantes or speed. The del() function is typically used to delete objects.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
import time

canvasWidth = 480
canvasHeight = 320

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvasWidth, height=canvasHeight, bg='white')
root.title('RaspPi')
canvas.pack()


class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
            self.ballSize = 30
            self.xposition = random.randint(0 + self.ballSize, canvasWidth - self.ballSize)
            self.yposition = random.randint(0 + self.ballSize, canvasHeight - self.ballSize)
            self.shape=canvas.create_oval(self.xposition,self.yposition,self.xposition+self.ballSize,self.yposition+self.ballSize, fill='black',width=0)
            self.xspeed = random.randrange(-3,3)
            self.yspeed = random.randrange(-3,3)

    def move(self):
        canvas.move(self.shape, self.xspeed, self.yspeed)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        if pos[2] >= canvasWidth or pos[0] <= 0:
            self.xspeed = -self.xspeed
        if pos[3] >= canvasHeight or pos[1] <= 0:
            self.yspeed = -self.yspeed


balls=[]
for i in range(20):
    balls.append(Ball())


def click(event):
    if canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT):
        canvas.delete(CURRENT)

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", click)

while True:
    for ball in balls:
        try:
            ball.move()
        except:
            del(ball)

    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

root.mainloop()
```

**UPDATE**

Just check in your method `move` if the list `pos` is not zero. If it is zero just delete the object itself. It is ok if you just delete the canvas but if you care for memory usage than this is the best option I can think of.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
import time

canvasWidth = 480
canvasHeight = 320

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvasWidth, height=canvasHeight, bg='white')
root.title('RaspPi')
canvas.pack()


class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
            self.ballSize = 30
            self.xposition = random.randint(0 + self.ballSize, canvasWidth - self.ballSize)
            self.yposition = random.randint(0 + self.ballSize, canvasHeight - self.ballSize)
            self.shape=canvas.create_oval(self.xposition,self.yposition,self.xposition+self.ballSize,self.yposition+self.ballSize, fill='black',width=0)
            self.xspeed = random.randrange(-3,3)
            self.yspeed = random.randrange(-3,3)

    def move(self):
        canvas.move(self.shape, self.xspeed, self.yspeed)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        if len(pos) != 0:
            if pos[2] >= canvasWidth or pos[0] <= 0:
                self.xspeed = -self.xspeed
            if pos[3] >= canvasHeight or pos[1] <= 0:
                self.yspeed = -self.yspeed
        else:
            del(self)




balls=[]
for i in range(20):
    balls.append(Ball())


def click(event):
    if canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT):
        canvas.delete(CURRENT)

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", click)

while True:
    for ball in balls:
        ball.move()

    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Is there any way to do it without using try and except?

Comment: Thanks! You're the best!